# How I can add an external API documentation Into Swagger using grape-swagger?

Tags: swagger, ruby-grape, grape-api

How I can add an external API documentation?

For example, I'm using doorkeeper, `POST /api/v1/token`
That's not a grape endpoint. How can I add this endpoint into swagger ?

Comment: I assume this is an authorization process?

Comment: I opened an issue on grape-swagger. They don't have this feature now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm facing the same problem today. I'm using Grape for my API, and using Doorkeeper as OAuth 2 provider. Doorkeeper provides several API endpoints, such as `POST /oauth/authorize`, `POST /oauth/token`.

I add a dummy `oauth` api class to my APIs, describing each end point using `desc` and `params`. Of course, I have to manually list all parameters (requires or optional, name, type, desc, values, etc.). But I leave the implementation blank. When user call these apis, the requests will be routed to Doorkeeper to perform the real action.

For example, my code about `POST /oauth/token` endpoint:

```
module API
  class Oauth < Grape::API
    resources :oauth do
      # POST /oauth/token
      desc 'Requires for an access token'
      params do
        requires :grant_type,
                 type: String,
                 values: %w(client_credentials authorization_code)
        optional :code,
                 type: String
        requires :client_id,
                 type: String
        requires :client_secret,
                 type: String
        optional :redirect_uri,
                 type: String,
                 default: 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
      end
      post :token do
      end
    end # resources :oauth

    add_swagger_documentation mount_path: 'oauth/swagger_doc',
                              api_version: '',
                              format: :json,
                              hide_format: true,
                              hide_documentation_path: true
  end
end
```

And the generated swagger doc:
[image]

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that grape does not overwrite the doorkeeper routes, I'm going to test.

Comment: it would be awesome if you could share their template doorkeeper oauth grape template